# Clone children to create looping scroll jQuery to Javascript conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a page infinitely scroll. I managed to do this in jQuery, but I would like to try and convert this to "vanilla" Javascript in order to forgo the jQuery dependency, however, the code I have written is not working, I am only able to clone it once and append and able to reset the scroll position.

Below is the version of the fully working jQuery:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {

    var documentHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;

    var clone=$("body").contents().clone();
    clone.appendTo("body");
    clone.prependTo("body");

    $(document).scroll(function(){ 

        var scrollWindowPos = $(document).scrollTop(); 

        if(scrollWindowPos >= documentHeight ) { 
            $(document).scrollTop(0); 
        }
        if(scrollWindowPos <= 0 ) { 
             $(document).scrollTop(documentHeight); 
         }        
    });
});
```

```css
.projects {
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="projects">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/Thomas_Cole_A_Wild_Scene.jpg">

  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Turquoise_Swirls_in_the_Black_Sea.jpg">

  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4c/Casa_hist%C3%B3rica_de_Tabatabaeis%2C_Kashan%2C_Ir%C3%A1n%2C_2016-09-19%2C_DD_65.jpg" >
<div>
```

The following is my attempt so far, the body does not get prepended and the scroll will not reset. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  const body = document.body
  const documentHeight = body.offsetHeight;
  
  const clone = body.cloneNode(true);
  body.append(clone);
  body.prepend(clone);
  
  body.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    var scrollWindowPos = body.scrollTop; 

    if(scrollWindowPos >= documentHeight ) { 
       body.scrollTop = 0; 
    }
    if(scrollWindowPos <= 0 ) { 
       body.scrollTop = documentHeight;
    }    
  });
});
```

```css
.projects {
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="projects">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/Thomas_Cole_A_Wild_Scene.jpg">

  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Turquoise_Swirls_in_the_Black_Sea.jpg">

  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4c/Casa_hist%C3%B3rica_de_Tabatabaeis%2C_Kashan%2C_Ir%C3%A1n%2C_2016-09-19%2C_DD_65.jpg" >
<div>
```

Comment: `const clone = body.cloneNode(true);` is trying to clone the body element.  Then you are trying to append, and prepend, the body to the body.  Body should only be the child of the document.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. I understand the problem now, I'm struggling to find the equivalent of jQuery's `.contents`. I have tried various things like `Array.from(body.childNodes).cloneNode(true)` with no success. What is the correct way of getting just the children?

Comment: Personally I'd be tempted to just use the innerHTML.  http://jsfiddle.net/zjbwcfna/3/ @CalAlt

Comment: Why don't you just clone the images one-by-one as you scroll, and just keep track of which image you're cloning to append them in order?